# How to use Simple FB Connect in decoupled Drupal

Tags: 8, social-network, authentication-authorization

I'm creating a Drupal 8 website which I need to be able to access via Facebook OAuth. The [Simple FB Connect](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_fb_connect) module has solved the signup/login issues quite well. Users can sign up to the website with Facebook as intended and it created a Drupal login flow as intended.

But now I also need to use the OAuth procedure I have in place with Drupal, when the client is a native mobile user, ie, Android phone, to use with a decoupled Drupal backend.

Something like, in a mobile app, the user selects "Login with Facebook" and that produces the same effect as using Facebook to login to Drupal, but now to use with REST services.

There is no documentation on the module's docs regarding this use case, so I'm suspecting it might not be possible in a straightforward manner.

Even so, I was wondering if simply sending the user's credentials to the backend and then having the OAuth token going back and forth would be enough. Does anyone have some experience with this use case?

Comment: Hi Joun I have also same problem, I want FB login via REST API for Drupal 8 but not found any tutorial, did you got something.

Comment: @vijay Sadly, not yet. But I'm thinking of going as suggested in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065492/rest-api-for-website-which-uses-facebook-for-authentication

Comment: Have a look at [youtube-dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/) (Bear with me on this!) youtube-dl is a command line utility for downloading videos from video sites and its written in Python. It provides an option to download private videos from Facebook whereby the user would be required to be logged in. It is that very thing - the mechanism where a user can be logged into to Facebook without using the web interface, which may give you some clues as to how to do the same in your Android app environment, by studying the code. Komodo IDE works well for debugging (don't work for them).